# Folder management app for iPhone photos?

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation, photos

Is there any iPhone app available that allows you to create folders in iPhone while using their Photos app?

It is kind a annoying that every time I must connect to iTunes and do the folder management there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an app"photo folder" which have some wonderful features:
It helps in creation of folders & sub folders for easy drag & Drop photo organization.
Allows to filter photos based on keywords,metadata,rating or by favorite.
It allows to create & assign new keywords to a photos metadata.
Arrange the order of photos using manual,name,date,size or ratings etc.Also we can play a slideshow & share photos on various social media sites.

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/photo-folder/id453985116?ls=1&mt=8

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there are a couple out there if you search the App Store for 'sort photo albums'. Of the results returned [Pics](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pics/id386097412?mt=8) looked the best to me. Plus it had an interesting WP7 style to it.

Comment: I believe that none of these actually manage your "native" iPhoe/iPad photo albums. They simply provide a viewer interface to those photos, and folders within that interface.

Answer (score 1):

The new iOS 5 has added this as one of its new features.